# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rack":

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, redmine

I am new to Ruby but actually I don't need it if I don't want to install Redmine. I am following the instructions at http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_install_Redmine_on_CentOS_Detailed

I have installed ruby 1.9 using

```
rvm install 1.9.3
```

and ruby gems using...

```
sudo yum install rubygems
```

Then coming to the part of creating the Gemfile and register these gems in it

```
# file: /var/www/redmine/Gemfile
source "http://rubygems.org" 
gem "rake", "0.8.3" 
gem "rack", "1.1.0" 
gem "i18n", "0.4.2" 
gem "rubytree", "0.5.2", :require => "tree" 
gem "RedCloth", "~>4.2.3", :require => "redcloth" # for CodeRay
gem "mysql" 
gem "coderay", "~>0.9.7"
```

and my file looks like...

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem "rake", "0.8.3"
gem "rack", "1.1.0"
gem "i18n", "0.4.2"
gem "rubytree", "0.5.2", :require => "tree"
gem "RedCloth", "~>4.2.3", :require => "redcloth" # for CodeRay
gem "mysql"


gem "rails", "3.2.15"
gem "jquery-rails", "~> 2.0.2"
gem "coderay", "~> 1.1.0"
gem "fastercsv", "~> 1.5.0", :platforms => [:mri_18, :mingw_18, :jruby]
gem "builder", "3.0.0"

# Optional gem for LDAP authentication
```

When I run

```
bundle install
```

it gives me...

```
Please configure your config/database.yml first
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rack":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.2.15) ruby depends on
      rack (~> 1.4.5) ruby

    rack (1.1.0)
```

I don't know what to do.

Comment: what version of Redmine you are trying to install? I don't see `rack` in [Gemfile](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/2.5-stable/Gemfile)

Answer (score 5):

You updated the rails version which required rack (1.4.5), where previous version was locked on rack (1.1.0), for a quick fix

remove the **gemfile.lock** and run **bundle install** again

hope it will resolve your problem...