# Fixing Bundler could not find compatible versions gem "rack"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was working on a GoRails refile gem course and trying to implement it into my app. When I tried to do bundle install, I kept running into an error message in my console saying that bundle could not find compatible versions for my gem "rack" (screenshot of error below).

I tried looking at these Stackoverflow questions - [Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rack": In Gemfile:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284591/bundler-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-gem-rack-in-gemfile) and [Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rack":](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22704671/bundler-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-gem-rack) without success.  I  tried multiple approaches - 1. putting rack in my Gemfile, 2. uninstalling all previous rack and then installing rack versions. None seemed to work.  I would greatly appreciate any help on this issue. Thank you so much.

[image]

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1', '>= 5.1.3'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-sass-rails', '~> 4.0', '>= 4.0.3.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.7'
gem 'devise', '~> 4.3'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 5.1'
gem 'redis'
gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem "twemoji"
gem 'koala', '~> 2.5'
gem 'chosen-rails'
gem 'devise-bootstrap-views', '~> 0.0.9'
gem 'pry', '~> 0.10.4'
gem 'bootstrap-modal-rails', '~> 2.2', '>= 2.2.5'
gem 'better_errors', '~> 2.3'
gem 'selectize-rails', '~> 0.12.4'
gem 'ransack', '~> 1.8', '>= 1.8.2'
gem 'searchkick', '~> 2.3', '>= 2.3.1'
gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails', '~> 0.4.7'
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end
group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
gem 'web-console'
gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: Are you using rbenv or rvm to manage your gems? If so, are you sure you're using the right environment/gemset?

Comment: @MarsAtomic thank you for your comment. I'm not sure I think its rbenv; I know that this issue only appears when I have inserted "gem "refile", require: "refile/rails" & 
gem "refile-mini_magick"; when I remove these two gems my gemfile can be bundle installed without issue

Comment: Kindly post your gemfile.

Comment: @MarsAtomic just posted it, thanks again mate

Comment: That's the version of the gemfile that installs, yeah? I didn't see refile in there. I'm assuming it just says `gem 'refile'` without any version information? Also, have you looked at this similar [issue](https://github.com/refile/refile/issues/416) on their report page? refile hasn't been touched in year or so, and I'm thinking that you might be out of luck.

Comment: @MarsAtomic thanks for the guidance, I'll try to explore another solution then. Have a great one

Comment: You can still use refile -- you just can't use it with Rails 5.x. Install Rails 4.3 or something like that (whatever was current when that GoRails video was made), along with whatever Ruby and Refile was current at that time. Then, when they fix the bug, you'll at least have the experience to reimplement with the current versions.

Comment: this is a good example of why screenshots are discouraged here ... the first image is not showing up.